# Memory leaks during decoding to Bitmap and compressing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bitmap, compression

I've been studying the following code which opens a stored image on an android tablet, decodes it into a Bitmap and then turns it into a base64 String so that it can be stored inside an SQLite DB.

To my knowledge, as much as 2MB of data is being leaked from this transaction, multiple calls to this function takes more and more memory that is not being correctly Garbage Collected.

Once origin_photo has been populated it occupies roughly 49kb and once it has been converted to base64 it occupies roughly 65kb.

The photo.insert function is a simple SQLite insert of base64 as well as a couple of pieces of small information. I do not envision it being a part of the problem.

After this function completes I also receive a message in log cat "Skipped 57 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" (This is without any break points slowing the code down)

I may be mistaken and it is a different section run close to this code that is causing the leak but this seems like the most likely candidate. Any help at all is much appreciated.

UPDATE: The base64.encodeBytes function is taken from

http://iharder.net/base64

```
public void savePhoto() 
{
    try
    {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        //Get last captured image in db
        String capturedImageFilePath = null;
        try
        {
            //NOTE: The warning on activity.managedQuert states you must NOT close the cursor it creates yourself 
            Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
            int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            //Get file path from last stored photo
            capturedImageFilePath = new String(cursor.getString(column_index_data));
            //cursor.close();
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            ErrorCodes.CreateError(ErrorCodes.DCDF_SAVE_PHOTO_GET_IMAGE_FILE_PATH, this.getActivity());
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            ErrorCodes.CreateError(ErrorCodes.DCDF_SAVE_PHOTO_GET_IMAGE_FILE_PATH, this.getActivity());
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            ErrorCodes.CreateError(ErrorCodes.DCDF_SAVE_PHOTO_GET_IMAGE_FILE_PATH, this.getActivity()); 
        }

        int orientation = -1;
        //Get Exif data from current image and store orientation
        //Note exif data will be stripped when this filepath is turned
        //into a bitmap
        try 
        {
            ExifInterface e = new ExifInterface(capturedImageFilePath);
            orientation = e.getAttributeInt("Orientation", -1);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            ErrorCodes.CreateError(ErrorCodes.DCDF_SAVE_PHOTO_EXIF_DATA_IO, this.getActivity());
        }
        catch(Exception e) { ErrorCodes.CreateError(ErrorCodes.DCDF_SAVE_PHOTO_EXIF_DATA_GENERAL, this.getActivity()); }

        //Decode current photo into a Bitmap
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath);

        if(b == null)
        {
            Log.d("activitycrossellcalls", "error open " + capturedImageFilePath);
            ErrorCodes.CreateError(ErrorCodes.DCDF_SAVE_PHOTO_NULL_BITMAP, this.getActivity());
        }
        else 
        {
            int width = -1;
            int height = -1;

            width = b.getWidth();
            height = b.getHeight();
            Log.d("activitycrossellcalls", "w: "+width+", h:"+height);
            //Scale down if too big
            int max = (width > height)?width:height;
            float ratio = 1;
            if(max > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE)
                ratio = (float)max/(float)MAX_IMAGE_SIZE;
            width /= ratio;
            height /= ratio;

            b = Photos.getResizedBitmap(b, height, width);

            Log.i("activitycrossellcalls", "new w: " + width + ", h: " + height);

            // Encode
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
            b.recycle();


            byte[] origin_photo = null;

            origin_photo = baos.toByteArray();

            // Insert               
            Photo photo = null;
            try
            {
                photo = new Photo();
                photo.base64 = Base64.encodeBytes(origin_photo);
                photo.call = DailyCallsDetailsActivity.call.id;
                photo.tag_id = TaggingActivity.currentTag.id;
                photo.orientation = orientation;
            }
            catch(Exception e) { ErrorCodes.CreateError(ErrorCodes.DCDF_SAVE_PHOTO_INIT, this.getActivity()); }

            photo.insert();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) { ErrorCodes.CreateError(ErrorCodes.DCDF_SAVE_PHOTO, this.getActivity()); }
}
```

.

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) 
{
    try
    {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        bm.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
    catch(Exception e) { ErrorCodes.ReportError(ErrorCodes.PHOTS_GET_RESIZED_BITMAP); return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath);
...
b = Photos.getResizedBitmap(b, height, width);
```

You aren't recycling the original b.  That shouldn't be a permanent leak, but it would definitely cause the GC to thrash.

You also may want to consider using an LRUCache to automatically cycle in and out bitmaps.

Comment: Hmm, curious. You're quite correct even though I seemed to solve the issue following Flynn's advice. I will correct this as well by adding a new Bitmap variable for the line you mentioned so I can recycle the original b. It probably explains why the memory wasn't being collected quickly on its own.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: Users experiencing similar issues should also view the answer and comments written by Flynn81 below

Comment: Especially if you're on pre-3.0.  In 3.0 they changed how bitmap memory was handled, from native data to Java managed data.  That's one of the reasons recycle exists-  Java can't collect that memory very well.  In pre-3.0 its pretty much only cleared when the finalizer is called

Answer (score 2):

Your decoding an image that is probably large.  Check the size of Bitmap b after this line in savePhoto():

```
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath);
```

After that you scale it down, so when you save to the db it will appear smaller.  My guess is your source file is large, which is causing more memory than you expected to be used.

Also, for the "skipped frames" message from logcat, usually that happens when you are performing a long running operation on the UI thread.  Make sure your methods are being called off of the UI thread, perhaps in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I agree, the image opened probably is quite large. What I don't understand is why it is staying in memory and not garbage collected once this function ends.

Comment: Bitmap memory is handled natively.  If you look at the source for Bitmap, many of the methods are "native" meaning the hardware manufacture provides the implementation.  When the bitmap's memory will actually be released is unknown, even if you call System.gc().  Best thing you can do is after calling recycle() on b, set b to null and call System.gc().

Comment: Check out the source for bitmap, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java, notice that recycle() just calls a native recycle method.  It's a problem I've run into before dealing with large bitmaps, and it's pretty frustrating.

Comment: Thank you very much, this appears to be working. The cleanup on this device must not be very efficient because if many photos were taken and then processed in this manner then it would not free the memory in time to stop an OutOfMemoryError.
Could you please add the comment on b=null and System.gc() to your answer above so I can mark it as correct? Thank you.

Comment: Correction: Based on Gabe's explanation the fact that it wasn't removing them now makes sense. Recycle wasn't called on the first b which meant the GC had more processing to do. By the time it catches up with the confusion another photo could have been taken and subsequent processing adding more stress. That means I probably don't even have to follow an explicit null and executeGC but I think will, just to be sure. (It's a good spot in the app to do so in any case)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your cursor.  May not be the only problem, but its one of them.

Comment: See the note written above the creation of it. The documentation specifies that this cursor will be closed by the activity.

UPDATE: Docs say: "Warning: Do not call close() on a cursor obtained using this method, because the activity will do that for you at the appropriate time. However, if you call stopManagingCursor(Cursor) on a cursor from a managed query, the system will not automatically close the cursor and, in that case, you must call close()."

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch you were using managed query.  I avoid that function just due to that confusion.  Also, its now deprecated.

Comment: I agree, once I've fixed the main issue I will look into replacing it.